# using VBA to find the last row of a merged cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use find the last row of a merged cell with text and hide all rows beside that

For example:

A1:A5 is a merged cell with text "A", A6:A10 is a merged cell with text "B", etc

I want to write a code that would find the last row of the merged cell with text "B", and would hide any rows above or below the merged cell.

At the moment I am defining the rows to hide manually, but these change frequently so my method is not very efficient.

Any suggestions on how to find the last row instead?

```
Sub FindLastRow()

Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test")

'Hide all rows above B
ws.Rows("1:5").EntireRow.Hidden = True

'Hide all rows below B
ws.Rows("11:80").EntireRow.Hidden = True

End Sub
```

Comment: `Application.Match` should be helpful.

Comment: I've never used that before, could you give an example of how I could incorporate it into my code?

Comment: Looks like you have an answer already with `Range.Find`, which accomplishes the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could try the following, making use of [`Range.Find`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) and [`Range.MergeArea`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.mergearea):

```
Sub Test()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test")
Dim fullRng As Range, fndRng As Range

Set fullRng = ws.Range("A1:A80")
Set fndRng = ws.Range("A1:A80").Find(What:="B", Lookat:=xlWhole)

If Not fndRng Is Nothing Then
    fullRng.Rows.Hidden = True
    fndRng.MergeArea.Rows.Hidden = False
End If

End Sub
```